# How to get input and write output from txt files in dart

Tags: dart, stdout, stdin

How to get input from stdin (from text file ) and write to stdout (to text file ) in dart lang ?

just like this one in python

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('inp.txt','r')
sys.stdout = open('out.txt','w')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `stdin` and `stdout` to read/write files. Could you explain a bit more?

On your example, the contents of `"imp.txt"` are not written to the file `"out.txt"`.

You can indeed write all the stdout contents to a file instead of the console in python. I am not sure if you can do the same on DART.

```py
import sys
sys.stdout = open('out.txt','w')
print('test') # anything that goes to stdout will be written to the "out.txt"
```

If you want to save all the output of a `dart` script to a file, you can still do it using the standard command line for it.

`dart dart_script.dart > out.txt`

To read the contents from one file and write to another you can use the class [`File`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.0/dart-io/File-class.html) from the module [`dart:io`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.0/dart-io/dart-io-library.html).

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  new File('inp.txt').readAsString().then((String contents) {
    new File('out.txt').writeAsString(contents);
  });
}
```

To make it more effective, and understand more of the structure you can treat them as streams

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final inpFile = new File('inp.txt');
  Stream<List<int>> inputStream = inpFile.openRead();

  final outFile = new File('out.txt');
  IOSink outStream = outFile.openWrite();

  outStream.addStream(inputStream);
  outStream.close();
}
```

[Stdin](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.0/dart-io/Stdin-class.html) is the equivalent to python `sys.stdin` and [Stdout](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.0/dart-io/Stdout-class.html) the equivalent to python `sys.stdout`.

`Stdin` is a `Stream`. And it's used to read input data from the command line. And `File.openRead()` returns a `Stream` as well.

So to print the contents of a file to `StdOut` you can use

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final inpFile = new File('inp.txt');
  Stream<List<int>> inputStream = inpFile.openRead();

  stdout.addStream(inputStream); //print all contents of file to stdout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe Dart's `dart:io` library allows you to override `stdin` or `stdout` the way `Python` does.

You can start a new process with [`Process.start`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-io/Process/start.html) and then write to its `stdin` or read from its `stdout`, but you can't change the `stdin`/`stdout` of the current process.